# How to initialize values inside onChanged function of AndroidViewModel

Tags: android

I have a AndroidViewModel and I am using a function that will give me a contact through id.

```
        chatViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(ChatViewModel.class);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        id = i.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);

        chatViewModel.getOneContact(id).observe(this, new Observer<UserContacts>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(UserContacts userContacts) {

                reciever = userContacts.getFriend();
                me = sender;
                profile = userContacts.getPicture();
                firstName = userContacts.getFirstName();
                lastName = userContacts.getLastName();
                friendPublicKeyString = userContacts.getFriendPublicKey();
            }
        });
```

And this is the Dao function that is ultimately being called

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM UserContacts WHERE id = :given_id")
LiveData<UserContacts> getAllDataRelatedToCurrentId(int given_id);
```

Now the problem is that the values inside onChanged are being initialized with null. Now I know that through debug that id is not null and is valid and the data related to id exists in Room database and the DAO function is being called too but values inside onChanged are being assigned  with null. Also I know this approach should work because in my code I am doing similar things and those worked but now I have to change code structure for some improvements and now its not initializing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but this would fix so at the end i uninstalled and reinstalled app and put new data in db and this is working now